# <esc>v$ without trailing space?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, cursor-motions, macvim, object-motions

I want to use `$` in visual mode but it always includes a trailing space (even if there isn't one on the line).

How do I make it so `$` only goes to the actual last letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control that with the [`'selection'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27selection%27) option. To disable the "past line" cursor behavior, use the following command:

```
set selection=old
```

Beware that using a non-default setting for this option is possibly likely to break behavior of some plug-ins, so it might not be a great idea to change it.

There's also a motion that might be close to what you want: [`g_`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#g_) moves to the last non-blank character of the line. It's not exactly the same as `$` with `selection=old`. For example, when there are trailing blanks. Also, using `$` will keep the cursor at the last character of the line as you move up or down, which is not the case if you used `g_`.

But `g_` will work without having to mess with the `'selection'` setting, so it's better in that sense.

Comment: Awesome, `g_` is also fairly easy enough to type. Thanks!